# Executing mailmerge removes all bookmarks. What's the alternative?

Tags: vba, ms-word, mailmerge

So my challange is this.

I've created a Word Macro Enabled Template (MS Word 2016) which creates a document using the MailMerge function using data from an Excel file which colleagues complete. 
Once completed, they add in their signature - a scanned jpeg file of their signature from a central network.

My code worked on the principle of attaching to a bookmark, unbeknown to me that when executing a MailMerge, it removes all bookmarks.

I am thinking that if I can change my code after `ActiveDocument` so that instead of looking for `Bookmark` it looks for specific text, I can then insert this text in the specific place in the Word template so when the MailMerge is executed it places their signature in that specific [text] place.

Is this possible?

Thanks in advance.

My code is

```
Sub CurrentUserSignature()

    Dim folder As String
    folder = "C:\\MacroTemp\\"

    Dim path As String
    path = folder & Application.UserName & ".jpg"

    Dim shape As InlineShape
    Set shape = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("Signature").Range.InlineShapes.AddPicture(path, False, True)

    With shape
        .LockAspectRatio = msoTrue
        .Height = CentimetersToPoints(4.3)
    End With
End Sub
```

`

Comment: Yes, it's possible. Start by recording a macro to search the text and incorporate that in your code. And I recommend you work with an `InlineShape`  not a Shape as that can be positioned more accurately. But if this is being executed by one user, why not simply insert the signature to the main merge document *before* executing the merge? Then you can continue to use the bookmark. A content control would also be a possible "target" instead of a bookmark as that will not be removed since multiple content controls can have the same name (unlike bookmarks).

Answer (score 0):

You could simply insert a borderless single-cell table, a Rich Text Content Control, or a Picture Content Control at the desired location in the mailmerge main document, then access each of those in the output document. If you use a borderless single-cell table, you can give it a fixed height and width so the inserted image's size is automatically constrained to fit.

Where multiple output documents are being produced, each to be signed by the same person, you might do better to insert the signature into the mailmerge main document before execution, then close that without saving changes post-merge.

Alternatively, especially if different records require different signatures and the relevant details can be gleaned from the data source, you can add field coding to the mailmerge main document to automatically add the signature images. See *Managing Mailmerge Graphics* in the **Mailmerge Tips and Tricks** thread at:
http://www.msofficeforums.com/mail-merge/21803-mailmerge-tips-tricks.html
or:
http://windowssecrets.com/forums/showthread.php/163017-Word-Mailmerge-Tips-amp-Tricks